# QML/C++ Changing the painted scene via a QML button

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a mixxed QML/C++ Application which overall works fine apart from one issue:
In a class `Foo` inheriting from `QDeclarativeItem` I want to paint a `QtMobility::QGeoMapData` and a `QGraphicsWidget`.
When a qml-button is pressed I switch the object which is painted from a `QtMobility::QGeoMapData` to a native `QGraphicsWidget` containing a scene. 
When the scene is filled during the construction of `Foo` this works as expected and the painter takes the native scene.
Alas, I need to create the QGraphisWidget dynamically when the button is pressed and destroy it later. The creation works well and the scene is populated but when the painter is called afterwards it hangs and the programm eats up all the system memory. Any suggestions how this could be solved ?

Comment: This might be due to ownership issues; look for cppownership in the declarative engine docs. (For ex., if you return a non-parented (to another QtObject) object ptr from a Q_INVOKABLE, js ownership is assumed, and the object will be garbage-collected).